# Unnest and bulk insert in PostgreSQL using .NET Npgsql

Tags: sql, .net, postgresql, npgsql, unnest

I am trying to make bulk insert with single command. It works for simple values like int/string, but it failed me when inserting to `jsonb` column.

My example of table:

`CREATE TABLE data_table2 (id INTEGER NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL, test jsonb, bar jsonb)`

My query from .NET (that works perfectly fine when used without `@c` parameter):

`"INSERT INTO data_table2 (id, name, test, bar) SELECT * FROM unnest(@a, @b, @c, @d)"`

I am creating `@a` param like this: `new NpgsqlParameter<int[]>(name, value)` which results in inserting row by row (just like I want). Now when I added next `@c` jsonb param it fails, and instead of inserting row by row I get an error `42883: function pg_catalog.unnest(jsonb) does not exist` which is a lie, cause I could insert it before for only id/string. Third parameter in .net looks like this:

`new NpgsqlParameter<string[]>(name, NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Jsonb) { Value = value.ToJson() }`

and `ToJson` method is doing:

`value.Select(x => Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore })).ToArray()`

I have tried changing query to:

`"INSERT INTO data_table2 (id, name, test) SELECT * FROM unnest(@a, @b, ARRAY[@c])"`
it worked, but first two columns where inserted without a problem, but third one only had 1 row inserted with all the results in it and rest of the rows were null.

Could someone take a look what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not passing in array of JSONB documents, you'll have to change the argument to

```
new NpgsqlParameter<string[]>(name, NpgsqlDbType.Jsonb | NpgsqlDbType.Array) { Value = value.ToJson() }`

//                                  ^^^ this is `jsonb[]` type
```

If it still causes the same error, make sure that ToJson actually returns array.

---

Another option is to send the JSONs as an array of strings and the convert it in the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO data_table2 (id, name, test, bar) SELECT a, b, c::jsonb, d::jsonb FROM unnest(@a, @b, @c, @d) foo(a, b, c, d)
```